# Can you use SQL in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql, query

Is there a way to use SQL on a shapefile dataset in QGIS? I am used to using SQL to analyze my data.

Comment: Aren't these file just your regular sqlite3 database files? In which case you can run sqlite3 directly rather than doing it through qgis.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Db Manager -> Virtual Layer to use SQL (SpatiaLite) in any type(datasource) of layer.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use [**Execute SQL**](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#execute-sql) tool.

- Select/add data source(s)

[image]

- Use SQL query using `input1` instead of layer/datasource name.

[image]

The tool returns a layer containing the query result.

[image]